# Why is there a rectifier diode connected to ground?

Tags: rectifier

On the schematics for this DC/DC converter, there is a diode D2 which is placed between V+ and V-

[image]
On the actual board, the value for D2 is a M4 400V rectifier.

What's the purpose of this rectifier? It doesn't seem to be doing anything?

Comment: I can't see V+ and V-. I'm blind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This diode is used for reverse polarity protection (with a fuse placed before IN+). When reverse voltage is applied the diode conducts and blows the fuse.

Comment: Yep, and here's a guy "with a suspicious accent" who blew it by trying to charge a reversed polarity battery. The diode sacrificed itself to save the power supply. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSXvqrEwssk